# How to request read receipt with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I have a GAE application which sends out email to my domain users in a Google Apps for Business environment. I am using JavaMail as described in [this article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail). Unfortunately I can't seem to find a way to ask for a read receipt. I looked at *Message* methods but nothing seems to suggest that it is possible. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're interested in knowing if a mail bounced, then use bounce notification https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce

For read receipts:
As far as I'm aware, you need to roll your own read receipt functionality. For example: Include an image(with a unique url) in the mail you send out. When the recipient opens the mail, the image is retrieved and you can determine whether the mail has been read. This has it's downsides; if they don't have images enabled, then you won't receive the notification.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer... Basically I need to create some sort of handler for bouncing notifications but I also need a way to make email bounce? With an image?

Comment: Hi, bounce notifications are for when an email address doesn't exist (and returns to sender). Read receipts are for when a recipient opens mail and you are notified that they read it. Appengine doesn't support read receipt functionality. If you want read receipts, then you'd need to implement your own tracking pixel approach (as discussed in the answer).

Comment: @raz3r Should I elaborate further?

Comment: If I understood correctly you're saying that when the user reads the email it makes a get to the image as well. That "get" comes with a bounce notification that I can handle? Creating an handler seems easy enough and we do have images enabled in our environment. I just don't understand how a get can somehow raise a bounce but I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: @raz3r You would need to setup a bounce notification handler (for emails that bounce) and a readReceipt handler (for the tracking pixel approach).

Comment: But... isn't the image that raise the bounce? Or do I have to raise the bounce in another way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47297/discussion-between-rob-curtis-and-raz3r)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appropriate headers on your message, as described in [Message Disposition Notification - RFC 3798](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3798.txt).  Not all mailers will honor MDNs, so you might find the tracking pixel useful as well.  But then some mailers won't display remote images, so in the end there's no guaranteed way of getting notified when a message is read.